# A while loop to add the digits of a multi-digit number together? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, function, while-loop, numbers, digits

I need to add the digits of a number together (e.g. 21 is 2+1) so that the number is reduced to only one digit (3). I figured out how to do that part.

However,

1) I may need to call the function more than once on the same variable (e.g. 99 is 9+9 = 18, which is still >= 10) and

2) I need to exclude the numbers 11 and 22 from this function's ambit.

Where am I going wrong below?

```
var x = 123;
var y = 456;
var z = 789;

var numberMagic = function (num) {
    var proc = num.toString().split("");
    var total = 0;
    for (var i=0; i<proc.length; i++) {
            total += +proc[i];
        };
    };

while(x > 9 && x != 11 && x != 22) {
    numberMagic(x);
    };
} else {
    xResult = x;
};

console.log(xResult);

//repeat while loop for y and z
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are the problems with your code

```
var x = 123;
var y = 456;
var z = 789;

var numberMagic = function (num) {
    var proc = num.toString().split("");
    var total = 0;
    for (var i=0; i<proc.length; i++) {
        total += +proc[i]; // indentation want awry
    }; // don't need this ; - not a show stopper
    // you're not returning anything!!!!
};

while(x > 9 && x != 11 && x != 22) {
    numberMagic(x); 
    }; // ; not needed
// because x never changes, the above while loop would go on forever
} else { // this else has no if
    xResult = x; // even if code was right, x remains unchanged
};

console.log(xResult);
```

Hope that helps in some way

Now - here's a solution that works

```
var x = 123;
var y = 456;
var z = 789;

var numberMagic = function (num) {
    while (num > 9) {
        if (num == 11 || num == 22) {
            return num;
        }
        var proc = num.toString().split("");
        num = proc.reduce(function(previousInt, thisValueString) {
            return previousInt + parseInt(thisValueString);
        }, 0);
    }
    return num;
}

console.log(numberMagic(x));
console.log(numberMagic(y));
console.log(numberMagic(z));
```

Comment: This was super helpful. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand what you want..
with this function you reduce any number to one single digit

```
while(num > 9){
  if(num == 11 || num == 22) return;

  var proc = num.toString();
  var sum = 0;
  for(var i=0; i<proc.length; i++) {
    sum += parseInt(proc[i]);
  }
  num = sum;
}
```

is it what you are looking at?

Comment: Yep, this is it. Thanks. Now I'm wondering why my code doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an example at [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q5u7d86o/3/) that you can turn any given number into a single digit:

Example input: **551**

- array of [5, 5, 1] - add last 2 digits
- array of [5, 6] - add last 2 digits
- array of [1, 1] - add last 2 digits
- array of [2] - output

Here is the actual code:

```
var number = 1768;
var newNumber = convertToOneDigit(number);
console.log("New Number: " + newNumber);


function convertToOneDigit(number) {
    var stringNumber = number.toString();
    var stringNumberArray = stringNumber.split("");
    var stringNumberLength = stringNumberArray.length;

    var tmp;
    var tmp2;
    var tmp3;

    console.log("Array: " + stringNumberArray);
    console.log("Array Length: " + stringNumberLength);

    while (stringNumberLength > 1) {
        tmp = parseInt(stringNumberArray[stringNumberLength - 1]) + parseInt(stringNumberArray[stringNumberLength - 2]);
        stringNumberArray.pop();
        stringNumberArray.pop();
        tmp2 = tmp.toString();
        if (tmp2.length > 1) {
            tmp3 = tmp2.split("");
            for (var i = 0; i < tmp3.length; i++) {
                stringNumberArray.push(tmp3[i]);
            }
        } else {
            stringNumberArray.push(tmp2);
        }
        stringNumberLength = stringNumberArray.length;

        console.log("Array: " + stringNumberArray);
        console.log("Array Length: " + stringNumberLength);
    }
    return stringNumberArray[0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function addDigits(n) {
  let str = n.toString().split('');
  let len = str.length;
  let add,
      acc = 0; 
for (i=0; i<=len-1; i++) {
  acc += Number(str[i]); 
} 
 return acc;     
}
console.log( addDigits(123456789) );   //Output: 45
```

Just make it a While loop, remember a While loops it's just the same as a For loop, only you add the counter variable at the end of the code, the same way you can do with a Do{code}while(condition) Only need to add a counter variable at the end and its gonna be the same. Only that the variable its global to the loop, I mean comes from the outside.

Ej.

```
let i = 0; //it's global to the loop, ( wider scope )

while (i<=x) {
  //Code line;
  //Code line;
  //Code line;
  //Code line;

  i++
}
```

**Now this is working with an outside variable and it's NOT recommended.. unless that var its local to a Function.**

Answer (score -2):

Please look at the this solution also

```
      var x = 123;
                        var y = 456;
                        var z = 789;
                        var numberMagic = function (num) {
                            var total = 0;

                            while (num != 0) {
                                total += num % 10;
                                num = parseInt(num / 10);
                            }
                            console.log(total);
                            if (total > 9)
                                numberMagic(total);
    else
return total;

                        }
```

//Call first time function
                        numberMagic(z);

Comment: you also return nothing from the function, making it useless